# Image is sticking to bottom of the div in my React Component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a react component called SectionHeader which just returns the custom header with props text. This is what is returned from inside the render function :

```
<div 
  id='header-text'
  style={{
    width:'100%',
    textAlign:'center',
    fontSize:'28px',
    lineHeight:'34px'
  }}
>
    <img src={require('./stroke.svg')} style={{marginRight:'50px'}} />
    {this.props.text}
    <img src={require('./stroke.svg')} style={{marginLeft:'50px'}} />
</div>
```

Now the `stroke.svg` is just `6px` in height but longer in width. Since `line-height` is `34px` it is stuck to the bottom of the div `header-text` somewhat like this:

_________  Header Text  __________

I need to add a `margin-top` of `-10px` to both `img` tags so that it is somewhat vertically centered like this:

--------- Header Text ---------

But it doesn't work.

What I have tried :

- Wrap all three children inside separate `div` tags and set `display` for them as `inline-blocks` and set `display` of `header-text` to `block`, then add negative margin to the `div`s containing the `img`. (Has no effect)
- Wrap the prop text inside a `div` with `display:inline-block` and add positive margin to it. (This just shifts all 3 children down by 10px)
- Wrap both `img`s inside `div`s with `display:inline-block` and add negative margin to them. (Has no effect)

What is the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to go with flex-box. Here is the CSS: `display: flex; align-items: center`. You would also have to wrap your text inside an element like a `span` for instance

```
<div 
  id='header-text'
  style={{
    width:'100%',
    textAlign:center,
    display: flex,
    alignItems: center,
    fontSize:'28px',
    lineHeight:'34px'
  }}
>
    <img src={require('./stroke.svg')} style={{marginRight:'50px'}} />
    <span>{this.props.text}</span>
    <img src={require('./stroke.svg')} style={{marginLeft:'50px'}} />
</div>
```

Comment: That works great! Just had to add `justify-content:center;` instead of `text-align:center;` and it was good to go. Thanks.